# Highchart: drawgraph based on chart name

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I know that we can alter the graph selecting the series as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var lineSeries = Highcharts.seriesTypes.line;
        var lineDrawGraph = lineSeries.prototype.drawGraph;
        lineSeries.prototype.drawGraph = function () {
```

Is there any way to select the lineSeries based on anything other than seriesType.line? for eg using chart name..

I need this function to be executed only for a line chart and not on all the line charts in my page. Unfortunately "lineSeries.prototype.drawGraph" gets called for all the line charts.

Comment: But generally, what is your goal, what you try to achieve? It will be helpful for us to find any workaround (except answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the type of your specific series like this:

```
Highcharts.charts[i].series[j].type
```

You can check the type of your series on a specific chart (`i`), and use foreach on `Highcharts.charts[i].series` and check if the type is `line` then add your `drawGraph` function.